# webpage in nodejs Cannot GET/

Tags: node.js, express

I installed nodejs and used npm init then i used npm install express --save. I have made my own app.js to define webserver and make it running on my localhost. Now i get error: Cannot GET/. Bellow is app.js code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

//here we add content to webpage .get or .post
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

//here we setup port
app.listen(1337, function(){
    console.log('port 1337');
});
```

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: Did you stop and start the node server again after adding the `app.get` call? This code seems to be fully functional to me. I created a new directory (named test), changed to that directory in command prompt, and issued `npm init` to create my package.json file, then `npm install express --save` to install the express module. I then copied your code as is, and pasted it to app.js, ran `node app` in the same directory, and went to `localhost:1337`, and received the message `Hello World!`. If I remove the whole `app.get` call for root, I see your error.